# Can "whatever" be split into two words?

Tags: confusables, compounds

I tend to write, "say *whatever* they want", but I'm always tempted to write "say *what ever* they want". Is it acceptable to split the word in this context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it is not acceptable to split the word in your context:

> say whatever they want

Here, *whatever* is a relative pronoun and it is always written as one word. The only instance where one will find *what ever* is in the interrogative. For example:

> - What ever does he want?
> - What ever does she do besides complain?

In these cases, *ever* (an adverb) modifies the pronoun *what* and, as such, it cannot and should not be compounded with *what*.

However, one could also have *whatever* as an interrogative pronoun:

> Whatever's wrong with you?

And, finally, *whatever*, as an adjective, can be used in the following manner:

> - Run whatever distance you can.
> - I'll take whatever solution you've got.

Comment: +1 Good explanation. Note that "what ever does he want?" and "whatever's wrong with you?" are not exactly standard usage, but rather informal or affected.

Comment: @Cerberus: totally agree

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, "what ever" looks weird in this context, because I parse it with the "ever" referring to "want", as just another, less stilted way of writing "what they ever (i.e., always) want".

The "ever" in "whatever" serves more for emphasis than for its literal meaning. For example, "what you want" refers to a single, definite thing, while "whatever you want" refers to a thing chosen from any number of indefinite things. "Whatever" implies uncertainty or arbitrariness, and thus cannot really ever be replaced with "what ever".

But constructions such as this with "what ever" in place of "whatever" are so archaic and peculiar that I imagine few people, upon seeing the former, would assume that it meant anything other than the latter.

So you can say whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems clear.  But I always have a tendency to want to split it up when I ask

> What ever happened to X?

Or

> I wonder what ever happened to her.